# How to get to the 2nd "span" tag and change the displayed text there?

Tags: jquery

I'm using JQuery v2.0 to get to the the "span" tag and change the text value from there.  But I'm getting the javascript error saying "object doesnt support property or method text".

Here's the html resposne in Firefox's firebug.

[image]

Excuse my typo below if there's any.  I'm able to get the objects when using "var $groupRows" with no problem.  It's the use of "text()" that don't work.

```
var jqGridGroups = $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'groupingView').groups;
if (jqGridGroups != undefined) {  //This means the columns aren't being grouped...
    var jqGridGroupsLength = jqGridGroups.length;
    for(var x = 0; x < jqGridGroupsLength; x++)
    {
        var $groupRows = $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).find(">tbody>tr.jqgroup>td").eq(1)[0];
        $groupRows.innerText.text("ddd");
        //$groupRows.text("eee");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `innerText` with javascript `DOM` object instread of `jQuery` object.

*Change*

```
 $groupRows.innerText.text("ddd");
```

*To*

```
$groupRows[0].innerText = "ddd";
```

or

```
$groupRows.text("ddd");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will either want to do,

```
var $groupRows = $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).find(">tbody>tr.jqgroup>td").eq(1);
$groupRows.text("ddd");
```

or,

```
var groupRows = $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).find(">tbody>tr.jqgroup>td").eq(1)[0];
groupRows.innerText = "ddd";
```